# Install latest version of R with all the packages on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, r

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I want to install R (latest version) on it. As the system version is older, it can't find this version from terminal line. I checked it with this command on the terminal line.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.6.1
```

Which resulted in -

```
Version '3.6.1' for 'r-base' was not found
```

I want to install this version with all it's packages. What is the correct process? Can I get all the package files and installation files to install all of it in one go from my terminal? Please suggest me an appropriate way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install R 3.6 (3.6.1 specifically) on Ubuntu 16.04, you need to add the r-cloud project repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
To do that, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/'

sudo apt update

sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

If you want to install another version, you need to build it from source then add the executables and libraries to your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You can get the source code from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/).

**Credit:** [How to install R 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 16 with apt-get?](https://superuser.com/a/1396709)

---

**Edit:** 
I am not sure how packages are managed in R. But I think that essential packages will be installed with R and if you want a specific package you need to install it using R package manager.
To install a package named 'foo' for example, run `sudo -i R` to open the R console then run `install.packages("foo")`.
For more details about which packages are installed and how to install additional packages check the [R README page](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)

Comment: Will this install all packages?

Comment: Yes, it should install all essential packages. Try it, if you encounter any error, comment it here and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: Ok, does "essential packages" imply that there are some uninstalled (inessential) packages? I literally want "all" the packages.

Comment: I don't know how packages are managed in R. But I think that essential packages will be installed and if you want some specific package you need to install it using R package manager (this is how it works in Python for example). Check the [R documentation](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) for more details about which packages are installed and how to install additional packages

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I just checked my R version. It is showing 3.2.3 :( Your method did not result in the latest version.

Comment: @Niranjan are you sure you don't have R 3.2.3 already installed before you try to install R 3.5?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101895/discussion-between-niranjan-and-singrium).