# How to install R Cran Ecdat Package?

Tags: package-management, r

I tried to install R Cran's Ecdat package by the link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ecdat/index.html but it gives error. Even if I try with a odl version. Tried through the R Studio installer. And  through downloading 'tar.gz' but also didnt work. I'm using a 3.6.1-3bionic R cran version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install latest version of R with all the packages on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194291/install-latest-version-of-r-with-all-the-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04/1194303#1194303)?

Comment: This is what I get: <ERROR: dependencies ‘RCurl’, ‘stringi’ are not available for package ‘Ecfun’
* removing ‘/home/eliezer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Ecfun’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Ecfun’ had non-zero exit status>

Comment: Check [this link](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/302) they seem to have the same issue as yours. I think you hsould install stringi out of R studio (according to what they said).

Comment: Thanks bro ... I'm trying this > update.packages(.libPaths()[1])

Comment: Still nothing... I try ti installing others pkgs but it didnt work. I will trya to remove R and reinstall it all.

Comment: Sorted out. I didn't have to reinstall R- But I noticed that before Ecdat you had to have Ecfun and Rcurl and stringi. I went by parts `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` on terminal and  `install.packages("RCurl")` in Rstudio. If necessary `install.packages("bitops")`. To activate the library just `library(RCurl)`. After this I can follow whit Ecfun pkg and Ecdat pkg. And... a can return to my work... happy for using only Linux in my machine.

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem, please post an answer describing the steps you did to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted out! Resolution Process:

1. Ecdat is related to Ecfun and both must be present. But I couldn't
   add any.
2. Reading the warnings, I realized that it was required the Rcurl
   package and the stringi. In addition to some specific libraries.
3. At the terminal: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`
4. No Rstudio: `install.packages (" RCurl ")`
5. If necessary: `install.packages (" bitops ")`
6. In the end just activate the packages in Rstudio manager or by command. Example: `library (RCurl)`

Thanks to @singrium for the help.
Links that helped me in the answer:
https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/302
https://medium.com/@zsadigov/install-rcurl-package-on-rstudio-9f7967f1f863
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Ecdat/versions/0.3-4